# JS Split String By Multiple Paired Delimiters

Tags: javascript

I have this string that I split whenever it finds two colons.

"for exam:ple thi:s string turns into"
["for exam","pls thi", "s string turns into"]

I do this with:

```
text.split(/(:.*?:)/g)
```

Afterward I interpret a string as "inside" the delimiter if it contains the characters I expect and none of those I don't.

How do I make it also extract another delimiter like $$...$$ as well as the original :...: but also include the delimiter somewhere so I can use different logic for it?

For context I'm parsing text into different react components.:...: includes addresses to embed a certain component, while $$...$$ includes MathJax.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the ideal result would be?

Comment: Please execute this & see the result: `console.log("for exam:ple thi:s string turns into".split(/(:.*?:)/g));`. It does not match what is noted in the question. In fact, a simple `console.log("for exam:ple thi:s string turns into".split(':'));` gets the result that's noted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You can try this regex with particular checks for `:...:` and `$$...$$` patterns

```js
const text = "for exam:ple thi:s string $$turns$$ into"

const partialStrings = text.split(/(:.*?:|\$\$.*?\$\$)/g)

for (const partialString of partialStrings) {
  if (partialString.startsWith(":")) {
    //TODO: Do your logic with `:...:` pattern
    console.log(partialString + " contains ':...:'")
    continue
  }
  if (partialString.startsWith("$$")) {
    //TODO: Do your logic with `$$...$$` pattern
    console.log(partialString + " contains '$$...$$'")
    continue
  }
  
  //no patterns
  console.log(partialString + " has no patterns")
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

You can simply split your string with `:`

```js
const data = "for exam:ple thi:s string turns into"

console.log(data.split(":"))
```

If you want to have similar behavior for `$$` and a reusable function, you can declare a function called `splitBy`

```js
const splitBy = (data, delimiter) => {
  return data.split(delimiter)
}

const data = "for exam$$ple thi$$s string turns into"

console.log(splitBy(data, "$$"))
```

Comment: Thanks,

The problem with this is 

1. It doesn't support multiple simultaneous delimiters

2. I don't get to know which of the result strings were inside the delimiter vs outside

3. I also don't get to know *which* delimiter they were inside. Is there a way to get that info from this?

Comment: So you mean delimiters can be mixed like `$$abc:xyz`? @RyanTremblay

Comment: Delimiters can be mixed like 

`This is a string and :this should have one behavior: while $$this should have another$$`

Where for normal text I'll render text, while for :...: I'll render another component, and for $$...$$ I'll render a third component. I'm mapping the result of the split to React components.

Comment: What if it's wrapped into each other like `This is a string and :this should $$have$$ on behavior: while $$this should have another$$`? @RyanTremblay

Comment: I’m not sure, maybe ignore the colons or handle it however markdown does **test *test* test**? Whatever behavior makes the entire thing easiest to implement. :…: is for embedding a component with a specific ID number while $$…$$ is for embedding arbitrary LaTeX/MathJax equations.